# Array Creation Must Have Array Size Or Array Initializer in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I got this error with a .dll and I'm trying to fix it:

https://pastebin.com/raw/tDDbb93n

The error is on the following line:

```
Logger.n("Saving {0}", new object[]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is what the error message says: add an array size, e.g. new object[5]; => you have to tell the compiler how many objects you want

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is quite simple actually: all you have to do is to declare the size of your array on the line you create and use it. Instead of **new object[]** you could try **new object[32]**. (or any size that helps you)

Hope this helps! ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the size of the object array.

Try this:
`Logger.n("Saving {0}", new object[10]);`